Reprojecting LiDAR Data with SRS
I am very newly exposed to LiDAR data and coordinate systems.  I am not a professional, rather someone who is trying to answer a local question regarding our watersheds.
I am looking at two sets of data off the NOAA site.  Below are two representative files:
https://rockyweb.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elevation/LPC/Projects/OR_OLCMetro_2019_A19/OR_OLCMetro_2019/LAZ/USGS_LPC_OR_OLCMetro_2019_A19_w2070n2788.laz
lasinfo64 output:
variable length header record 2 of 2:
  reserved             0
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            2112
  length after header  949
  description          ''
    WKT OGC COORDINATE SYSTEM:
    COMPD_CS["NAD83(2011) / Conus Albers + NAVD88 height - Geoid12B (m)",PROJCS["NAD83(2011) / Conus Albers",GEOGCS["NAD83(2011)",DATUM["NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","1116"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6318"]],PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",23],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["meter",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6350"]],VERT_CS["NAVD88 height - Geoid12B (m)",VERT_DATUM["North American Vertical Datum 1988",2005,AUTHORITY["EPSG","5103"]],UNIT["meter",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Up",UP],AUTHORITY["EPSG","5703"]]]

https://noaa-nos-coastal-lidar-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/laz/geoid18/8873/45122D7403.laz

lasinfo64 output:
variable length header record 2 of 2:
  reserved             0
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34735
  length after header  48
  description          'LAS Georeferencing'
    GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 5
      key 1024 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 2 - GTModelTypeGeoKey: ModelTypeGeographic
      key 2048 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 4152 - GeographicTypeGeoKey: look-up for 4152 not implemented
      key 2054 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9102 - GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey: Angular_Degree
      key 4096 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 5703 - VerticalCSTypeGeoKey: NAVD88 height (Reserved EPSG)
      key 4099 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9003 - VerticalUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Foot_US_Survey
the header is followed by 2 user-defined bytes
reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...

The files size of these precludes the use of the lastools due to point count, so I have been using pdal.
The 2019 data processes well and I have been able to process the data through to a DEM, using the attached pipelines (one for tiling prior to masking, one for DEM).  I know these are not elegant.
{
    "pipeline": [
     {
         "type":"readers.las"
     },
     {
        "type": "filters.splitter",
        "length": "200"
     },
   {
        "type":"filters.overlay",
        "dimension":"GpsTime",
        "datasource":"nad83mask.shp"
    },
     {
        "type": "filters.range",
        "limits": "GpsTime[:1.0]"
     },
     {
        "type": "filters.range",
        "limits": "Classification[2:2]"
     },
   {
        "type": "writers.las"
    }
   ]
}

---  I know this is sloppy to write over the GPS time ---
{
    "pipeline": [
     {
         "type":"readers.las"
     },
     {
        "type": "filters.range",
        "limits": "Classification[2:2]"
     },
     {
        "type":"filters.reprojection",
        "out_srs":"EPSG:4979"
     },
       {
         "gdaldriver":"GTiff",
         "output_type":"mean",
         "resolution" :".000005",
         "type": "writers.gdal"
       }
   ]
}

at the end of this I get a DEM file for the watershed areas I am looking at
this same approach does not work for the 2009 data.
And, I have been unable to reproject successfully that set of data.  The pipelines appear to work, but the split length need to be much smaller (~0.001).  I assumed this was due to the different scaling factors in the different files, but the output is not legible by QGIS.
The input of the 2009 data, is readable by QGIS, so I suspect that this is a SRS definition issue somewhere in the 2009 data, but I cannot figure this out.
Is there a "simple" way to "fix" the 2009 data so that it can be reprojected to match the 2019 data?

I don't know the solution because I don't use LiDAR data, but the CRS of the first file is in a projected coordinate system, based on NAD83(2011) and both horizontal and vertical units are in meters. The 2nd file is in lat/lon degrees, NAD83(HARN), and the vertical units are US survey feet.  The difference between HARN and 2011 shouldn't be too much (probably cm to maybe decimeter level) and data accuracy is likely larger anyway.
